# Compare received and generated JSON in python

Tags: python, json, cucumber

I'm using python with cucumber, and I want to assert received from the service JSON, and the JSON, that I've set up in the table using key/value pairs.

My received JSON looks like this:

```
{
   'student': 'John',
   'age': 20,
   'attr`: {}
}
```

But, with cucumber, I get extra quotes near the age and attributes

```
{
   'student': 'John',
   'age': '20',
   'attr`: '{}'
}
```

I was able to bypass the quotes near int by using try-parse, so I parse the cucumber table with the following:

```
   expected = {}
   for row in table:
        try:
            value = int(row["value"])
        except ValueError:
            value = row["value"]
        expected[row["field"]] = value
```

But I don't know how to get rid of the quotes near `{}`

Comment: ` eval("{}")` will give you `{}`

Comment: @abhilb am I moving in the right direction by removing these quotes? Maybe there is a more useful function to remove all quotes from JSON where possible?

Comment: @abhilb after eval("{}") my `assert_that(actual, equal_to(expected))` return `undefined` result, but with `value = int(row["value"])` it worked fine